# How do I use different CSS reset stylesheets through CRA?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

There is a section in `create-react-app` about [adding a css reset](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-css-reset).

From what I understand, CRA includes `PostCSS Normalize` as a dependency, and all you need to do is create a css file and add `@import-normalize;` to it, and you will have `normalize.css`. (By the way, my editor gives me "Unknown CSS at-rule" with this `@import-normalize`).

What I want is a reset that includes having the margin on `body` be zero. I can't even tell if the reset is being applied just by looking at my app. I just want to make sure: this setting is not actually included in the `normalize.css` that is included by following the instructions?

Also, where can I find an explanation of what `@import-normalize` means? I haven't seen this syntax before.

Finally, is there a way through CRA to use a different reset file, or should I just install another one and import it as usually done?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of background on normalize.css 
http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/

With CRA you can normalize/reset CSS with any method you like. You just need to create a stylesheet with the reset/normalized CSS rules in it and import it into App. i.e `import './myCustomReset.css`

or you can also add the reset CSS file to the public folder, and add it as a link tag to your index.html. i.e `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./customResetStyles.css">`

I tend to use https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6 whenever I need to reset styles instead of just normalizing.